# How to decode data into a struct and store it?

Tags: solidity, abi

I am trying to make a function that takes in abi-encoded data and decodes it into a struct and stores the struct's values in my smart contract. To generate the encoded data, I am using ethers.js

```
    const encodedData = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder().encode(
      ["uint", "uint"],
      [mintingInfo.tokenId, mintingInfo.amount]
    );
```

This data is then sent to my function:

```
    function mintTokens(string memory message) external
    {
        ClaimInfo memory claimInfo = decodeClaimInfo(bytes(message));
        _accountToTokenBalances[msg.sender][claimInfo.tokenId] = claimInfo.amount;
    }

    function decodeClaimInfo(bytes memory message) public pure returns (ClaimInfo memory)
    {
        return abi.decode(message, (ClaimInfo));
    }
```

When I call just the 'decodeClaimInfo', it returns the correct information, for example:

```
0:tuple(uint256,uint256): 1,1000
```

But when calling the 'mintTokens' with the same exact data, the transaction succeeds but the mapping does not get updated.

I even stored the value of 'claimInfo' in a state variable to view the value of it after the function finished and it was set to:

```
0:
uint256: tokenId 21923370962747092222049241656982978670225693601166209560647359695041422438448
1:
uint256: amount 21796157974083048550319244236929488537086114760591164995662604048548353814576
```

Is there something that I am missing here? Why does the data suddenly change after returning from 'decodeClaimInfo' and the mappings don't get updated?

Comment: It's because it interprets strings in a different way. Can you change `mintToken` to have as input `bytes memory message` ?